# Reusable *button* in Xcode

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I've created an actionSheet with 3 options that push to other view controllers and call a number. This option is on a button on a navigation bar on each screen of my app. I'm trying to find a way to reuse the code without literally re-typing it for every screen. I understand there is a way to do this through subclassing a `UIButton` but I've searched for days and can't find a definitive answer on how to actually code the subclass. My code right now is the following:

```
class moreButton: UIButton {

@IBAction func displayActionSheet(_ sender: Any) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Get Your Roast On", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let followAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Follow Us", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!)->Void in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveSegue", sender: self)
    })
        let shopAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Visit Shop", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!)->Void in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "shopSegue", sender: self)
    })
        let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call Us Now", style: .default) { _ in
            let url:URL = URL(string: "tel://number")!
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

    }

    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alertController.addAction(followAction)
    alertController.addAction(shopAction)
    alertController.addAction(callAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)


    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> value of type 'moreButton' has no member 'performSegue'

in both the followAction and shopAction lines and "value of type 'moreButton' has no member 'present'" on the last line. This code was working when I had created an `IBAction` directly from the button but now it seems to have errors that I'm not sure how to correct.

Comment: You're trying to make a button do work that is properly the business of a view controller.  View controllers can perform segues and present other controllers but buttons can't, therefore the `self` has no idea what you're asking for.  Consider putting this code in a subclass of `UIViewController` and then having all your other "screens" inherit from that VC.

Comment: That is really helpful to know. I just assumed that because it worked with an IBAction from a button that it would work if I subclasses a button. I'm now running into a few issues from the below code but I'll see if it works out

Comment: The idea is that an IBAction is something that the button causes to happen on its behalf, not something the button does for itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting those errors because `performSegue` and `present` are UIViewController methods.

Instead of subclassing UIButton, I'd create a new helper class, with a class method to build the UIAlertController for you. The method would accept a UIViewController as its parameter, so that it can build the UIAlertActions correctly.

You'd call this new method from `displayActionSheet` like:

```
let alertController = ActionSheetBuilder.build(viewController: self)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Adapting your creation code into the new class would come out something like:

```
final class ActionSheetBuilder {
    class func build(viewController: UIViewController) -> UIAlertController {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Get Your Roast On", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let followAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Follow Us", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!)->Void in viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveSegue", sender: viewController) })
        let shopAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Visit Shop", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!)->Void in viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "shopSegue", sender: viewController) })
        let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call Us Now", style: .default) { _ in
            let url:URL = URL(string: "tel://2845471035")!
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(followAction)
        alertController.addAction(shopAction)
        alertController.addAction(callAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancel)

        return alertController
    }
}
```

Comment: This partially worked. I originally had placed the alertController within viewDidLoad so I've moved that now but I'm receiving the error: "cannot convert value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> 'displayActionSheet' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'". I'm also receiving 'expected declaration' on the present(alert....) line